# Using Jolt Spec how to reverse reduce a list of dictionary by a key using

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, transformation, jolt

Using the following code I was able to map a list of dictionaries by a key

```
import json

values_list = [{"id" : 1, "user":"Rick", "title":"More JQ"}, {"id" : 2, "user":"Steve", "title":"Beyond"}, {"id" : 1, "user":"Rick", "title":"Winning"}]
result      = {}

for data in values_list:
  id    = data['id']
  user  = data['user']
  title = data['title']
  if id not in result:
    result[id] = {
    'id' : id,
    'user' : user,
    'books' : {'titles' : []}
    }
  result[id]['books']['titles'].append(title)

print(json.dumps((list(result.values())), indent=4))
```

Knowing how clean is Jolt Spec and trying to separate the schema outside of the code.
Is there a way to use Jolt Spec to achieve the same result.

The Result

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user": "Rick",
    "books": {
      "titles": [
        "More JQ",
        "Winning"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user": "Steve",
    "books": {
      "titles": [
        "Beyond"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three levels of consecutive specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,id).&",
        "title": "@(1,id).books.&s[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "ONE",
        "user": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

- in the first spec, the common `id` values are combined by `"@(1,id)."` expression
- in the second spec, the integer keys(`1`,`2`) of the outermost objects are removed
- in the last spec,only the first of the repeating elements are picked

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros! It works like charm! now I will just need to automate the creation of the Jolt Spec to generate different schemas for different columns names.

Comment: quick question please, is there a good Python package to run Jolt Specs that you could recommend? it would be very appreciated!

Comment: Hi @mongotop, unfortunately, never studied for such a relationship between Python and Jolt

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros for getting back to me. how do you usually run your Jolt Specs against your data besides using the jolt website?